# How do I enable spellcheck in Microsoft OneNote 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

How do I enable spellcheck in Microsoft OneNote 2010?

Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have 2007 so I can't check 2010 for sure, but I'm going to guess you click this button,

[image: File menu]

Go to "options", and then click the "proofing" tab.  This should have all the settings you need, but I think "check spelling as you type" is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Verified. 2010 version has the same settings page.